# How to inject application service into AuthenticationHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector

I have a custom `AuthenticationHandler<>` implementation that depends on application service. Is there a way to resolve dependencies of `AuthenticationHandler` from Simple Injector? Or maybe cross-wire registration so that applications services can be resolved from `IServiceCollection`?

Sample implementation can look as follows for simplicity:

```
public class AuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private readonly ITokenDecryptor tokenDecryptor;

    public SecurityTokenAuthHandler(ITokenDecryptor tokenDecryptor,
        IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
        ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) :
        base(options, logger, encoder, clock) =>
        this.tokenDecryptor = tokenDecryptor;

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() =>
        return tokenDecryptor.Decrypt(this);
}

...

services.AddAuthentication("Scheme")
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, AuthHandler>("Scheme", options => { });
```

Current solution is to manually cross-wire application service which is not quite convenient:

```
services.AddTransient(provider => container.GetInstance<ITokenDecryptor>());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tao's answer is right. The easiest way to implement this is to *cross wire* the `AuthHandler` to Simple Injector.

This can be done as follows:

```
// Your original configuration:
services.AddAuthentication("Scheme")
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, AuthHandler>("Scheme", options => { });

// Cross wire AuthHandler; let Simple Injector create AuthHandler.
// Note: this must be done after the call to AddScheme. Otherwise it will
// be overridden by ASP.NET.
services.AddTransient(c => container.GetInstance<AuthHandler>());

// Register the handler with its dependencies (in your case ITokenDecryptor) with 
// Simple Injector
container.Register<AuthHandler>();
container.Register<ITokenDecryptor, MyAwesomeTokenDecryptor>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Comment: Great, basically it's one step further: to register the handler itself instead of a service which makes maintenance much easier. And thanks for the hint on ordering!

Comment: In net core 3.1, after I use services.AddTransient<AuthHandler> the services have 2 registration for AuthHandler and always the first one is picked up. I would suggest to remove the first AuthHandler registration before adding your own. Maybe you could update your answer reflecting changes in net core 3.1.
Rest of the provided solution works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> maybe cross-wire registration so that applications services can be
>   resolved from IServiceCollection?

No, it is impossible for .Net Core to resolve service from Simple Injector automatically.

> *Cross-wiring is a one-way process. By using
>   AutoCrossWireAspNetComponents, ASP.NET’s configuration system will not
>   automatically resolve its missing dependencies from Simple Injector.
>   When an application component, composed by Simple Injector, needs to
>   be injected into a framework or third-party component, this has to be
>   set up manually by adding a ServiceDescriptor to the
>   IServiceCollection that requests the dependency from Simple Injector.
>   This practice however should be quite rare.*

Reference:[Cross-wiring ASP.NET and third-party services](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html#cross-wiring-asp-net-and-third-party-services).

As the suggestion from above, you need to register the service in `IServiceCollection`. Which you currently has implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I was using **.Net 5** and the original provided by [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) no longer worked for me after I upgraded from my older .net core app. I had to:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddAuthentication("MyScheme")
        .AddScheme<ApiKeyOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>("MyScheme", o => { });

    var authHandlerDescriptor = services
        .First(s => s.ImplementationType == typeof(ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler));

    services.Remove(authHandlerDescriptor);

    services.AddTransient(c => container.GetInstance<ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I've just checked and I had to make same changes when upgrading to .net 5. Or maybe it was during `WebHost` -> `GenericHost` migration.

Comment: Glad to share! Mine was `WebHost` -> `GenericHost` because I was still using WebHost on .net 5 when the other way was working